# Redux: Why do we need actions?

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx

I'm working with NgRx to implement Redux. I'm trying to understand the redux pattern. Why do we need to dispatch an action? Why can't we just call the `userReducer` function directly from the service code below passing the correct action? Thanks!

Service code:

`this.store.dispatch(new userActions.SetName({"bob"})`

user.action.ts:

```
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.SET_NAME
    constructor(public payload: string) { }
    }
```

user.reducer.ts:

```
export function userReducer(
   state: UserState = BEGINNING_STATE
   action: UserActions
)
switch(action.type) {
case UserActionTypes.SET_NAME:
   return {
      ...state,
      Name: state.Name
   }
}
```

Comment: sounds like it's time to take https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview or even https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts because the official tutorials are very well written, and cover everything you want to know about redux.

Comment: As the author of those tutorials: yes, I agree, and I'm _really_ happy to see people recommending them :)

Comment: Thank you Mike and Mark. The articles helped reinforce my understanding of 'what' redux is. However, I'm still not clear on 'why' we need actions instead of just calling the reducer directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seperate "indicate something happened" (action) from "do this if X happened" (reducer/middleware). If you call reducer directly then you don't have this separation so if you refactor a button that dispatched INCREMENT to a button that executes one specific reducer you just changed the code to having a button that when clicked indicates INCREMENT happened to having a button that when clicked changes the state in a particular way. There are many advantages that this separation can have in big complex applications.

Facebook had a large app where multiple people in multiple locations in the world worked on (facebook chat) and in this app there are multiple components that should indicate something happened but would instead directly change the state or caused side effects that broke other people's code. So they came up with a pattern that fixed this. Developers could now create components that would only indicate that something happened so other developers could write the code what needs to done when certain things happen.

The redux devtools save the actions and the resulting state so debugging can be made easier. If something doesn't work the first thing you should do is check the devtools to see if the correct actions are dispatched and they changed the state correctly.

Writing to state with actions and reducers is just one part, you should use [selectors](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) to read state in a composable and re usable way.

Comment: Thank you HMR. I think I have a better idea now of the benefits. Is using actions analogous to using a broker in publisher-subscriber?

Comment: @user3667098 Exactly, you can [use subscribe](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener) to add change listeners to the store. This is done by react-redux so when the change listener is invoked redux will re render components if mapStateToProps or useSelector returns a different value than last time.