# Does mapStateToProps in component file make sense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux and so far I find it really, really confusing.

In all tutorials I've seen so far, the `mapStateToProps` function is included in the component file itself, for example (I removed irrelevant parts if the snippet):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import CartItem from '../cart-item/cart-item.component';

const CartDropdown = ({ cartItems }) => (
  <div>
      {cartItems.map(cartItem => (
        <CartItem key={cartItem.id} item={cartItem} />
      ))}
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ cart: { cartItems } }) => ({
  cartItems
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CartDropdown);
```

I don't get it how does it make sense to put `mapStateToProps` in the component file, as it makes my component dependent on the Redux state. Why all the hassle with passing it to props if we only use the Redux state?

Bonus commentary: I'm not gonna lie, Redux gives me a bit of a headache so far. I don't understand why the boilerplate is so huge. Adding any new Redux state property looks like a chore. Does it only make sense in huge apps in general? The idea of having actions, reducers, dispatchers, mappers, stores and a provider for mostly simple tasks is tough.

Comment: If you want to make the component reusable and not tightly coupled to Redux, make a wrapper for it and have that wrapper connect to Redux and pass in the props. That way you have a Redux version, but the actual component itself is still reusable elsewhere.

Comment: @Jayce444 I don't understand the balance of Redux so far. It's really complex with all these layers, I thought its main purpose was to allow global state while keeping the components reusable. If not, why can't I just call the state value directly, without all these actions and dispatchers?

Comment: I have completely no idea why do you think that components are not reusable because they are connected with the redux store. If you want your component to sometimes rely on the store props and sometimes on passed props, just export both of them (connected & unconnected) and use them interchangeably depending on your needs. "_the name of the state field becomes a hardcoded dependency._" - do you want the field names to become dynamic?

Comment: @kinduser The purpose of having props is to be able to fill them with whatever, depending on the context. If not, it's like creating a function just to call it with hardcoded parameter value. The idea of exporting the component in several contexts sounds more practical, but still - I've always thought that a good React component is one unaware of the context using it. If the component is well-written, I can copy the file untouched to another project. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well there's technical reasons behind the design of Redux, there's lots of articles which deep dive into that. But if you essentially just want a centralised store without the boilerplate that redux has, there are options, such as Zustand. But again, the points about reusability remain unchanged, for 100% reusability you need a pure prop based version and a store based version

Comment: What is blocking you from filling the store (and all of these particular fields that the component relies on) with data you like? You can fill the store with anything you like.

Comment: @Jayce444 yes, that sounds reasonable. That's why I find having `mapStateToProps` in my component's file an anti-pattern.

Comment: @kinduser my component doesn't rely on it. It's this single instance of my component that does.

Comment: @kinduser perhaps it will become cleaner to me when I get my hands on the hooks and context API, which - I suppose - can solve prop drilling in a much more straightforward way. I'm impressed with people who are fluent in Redux, as to me it's black magic so far. I feel like it wants me to run marathon around my house to buy groceries from the store 2 blocks away.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should understand the purpose of redux, why are you using redux in the first place. By default ReactJS providing React hooks or `setState` for you to manage state, which works great on component level, but as soon as your apps grows, most likely there are more than one components needed to access the same state.

Solely because of the problem above, you have many options available to solve that. Redux, React Context, Mobx. All of them are being categorized as **State Management Library**. Definitely they all have their pros and cons and I'm not here to push to any one of the library, you can easily google around to see the comparison between them and select base on your use case.

Now back to your question if `mapStateToProps` make sense, it totally is, abstract away all the complexity, how do a component receive external data? It's only via `props`

Comment: I know it's via `props`, but having `mapStateToProps` there, prevents my component from being reusable as-it-is. Now, the name of the state field becomes a hardcoded dependency. As for the use cases of Redux etc., I'm aware of them.

Comment: If your problem is about that, perhaps you can take a look at https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: If you want your component to be usable without connecting it to redux, just export it. You'll have to pass the props when you compose it, but it's 100% do-able

Comment: I'm new to Redux. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I really struggle to see any sense in using props just to always fill them with the state value. Why would I want to create these 10 layers of logic around it if all it does is reading the `cart.cartItems` from my state?

Comment: It's so the parent component doesn't need to know all the things its children need to know. If a sidebar contains a list of ice cream flavors, the sidebar only needs to know how to make a list. The list can connect to redux and get all the flavors. This is helpful when the sidebar also has lists of cones, and toppings, and syrups. The sidebar's state only has to contain info that is pertinent to the sidebar. The lists can get their state from the app.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Yes, I get that and I made an example with the component in-between that doesn't want to have the prop that its child needs. But still, I don't see having `mapStateToProps` tightly coupled to the component any better than having a direct read of the Redux state, which as far as I know is not possible. Something like `Redux.foo.bar` instead of `props.bar`. If it's tightly coupled anyway, a direct read would do the same thing, except it wouldn't go through 10 layers to read that value and I wouldn't need to create multiple files.

Comment: MapStateToProps lets redux know when to trigger a component rebuild. If the component was directly tied to the data, the component wouldn't be able to rebuild if an object changed. Maybe a primitive could trigger a rebuild, but it seems dicey.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I think I need to have rest and get back to it tomorrow. It does intrigue me why is it so complex, while all it does is keeping a global data and take care of refreshing components.

Comment: @RoboRobok I explained some of the advantages of using redux [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782931/1641941). If you use context api instead of redux you may still want to separate getting the context (container) from rendering it (component).